# Is it possible to prevent users to modify printer options in CUPS?

Tags: linux, printing, cups, printer, account-restrictions

A small family setup...

I have a color printer, and a Linux computer, with CUPS installed. I wan to allow the kids to print, but only in draft mode, and only in greyscale.

With CUPS I prevented the kids' account from accessing the printer. Then I set up a second printer, for the same hardware printer, but with different default options (draft and greyscale), and allowed the kids to access this new printer.

It works, when they print the default options for this new printer are indeed draft and greyscale. But they are just that, default options. They can change it.

Is there a way to prevent users from changing the options of a printer ?

Comment: `man lpoptions`

Comment: lpoptions sets the options before printing. It doesn't give a way to prevent users from settings specific options

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood: http://jeromebelleman.gitlab.io/posts/configuration/printeroptions/ sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with meuh's help, it was actually quite easy to implement a working solution.

Edit the printer's PPD, locate the GUI entries concerning the color setup and printing mode, and comment out the unwanted options (comments are lines starting with `*%` in a PPD file).

In my case, it was :

```
*OpenUI *ColorModel/Output Mode: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *ColorModel
*DefaultColorModel: KGray
*%*ColorModel RGB/Color: "<</cupsColorSpace 1/cupsBitsPerColor 8/cupsRowStep 0>>setpagedevice"
*%*ColorModel CMYGray/High Quality Grayscale: "<</cupsColorSpace 1/cupsBitsPerColor 8/cupsRowStep 1>>setpagedevice"
*ColorModel KGray/Black Only Grayscale: "<</cupsColorSpace 1/cupsBitsPerColor 8/cupsRowStep 2>>setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *ColorModel

*OpenUI *OutputMode/Print Quality: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *OutputMode
*DefaultOutputMode: FastDraft
*%*OutputMode Normal/Normal: "<</OutputType(0)/HWResolution[600 600]>>setpagedevice"
*OutputMode FastDraft/Draft: "<</OutputType(-2)/HWResolution[300 300]>>setpagedevice"
*%*OutputMode Best/Best: "<</OutputType(1)/HWResolution[600 600]>>setpagedevice"
*%*OutputMode Photo/High-Resolution Photo: "<</OutputType(2)/HWResolution[1200 1200]>>setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *OutputMode
```

Easy !

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the only way to do this is to copy the PPD file and remove the appropriate options, creating a new filename and model name. Since the file format from Adobe is fairly complex ([pdf](https://www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/PostScript/5003.PPD_Spec_v4.3.pdf)), to avoid side-effects, the options could be kept but manipulated to not work.
For example, a Brother printer PPD has the stanza:

```ppd
*OpenUI *TonerSaveMode/Toner Save: PickOne
*DefaultTonerSaveMode: Off
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup  *TonerSaveMode
*TonerSaveMode Off/Off: "statusdict/tonersave known{statusdict begin false tonersave end}if"
*TonerSaveMode On/On: "statusdict/tonersave known{statusdict begin true tonersave end}if"
*CloseUI: *TonerSaveMode
```

This creates a boolean option to save toner, the default being off. You could try changing the default to `On`, and removing the off option:

```ppd
*OpenUI *TonerSaveMode/Toner Save: PickOne
*DefaultTonerSaveMode: On
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup  *TonerSaveMode
*TonerSaveMode On/On: "statusdict/tonersave known{statusdict begin true tonersave end}if"
*CloseUI: *TonerSaveMode
```

In principle, providing a menu with just one choice might work.

Or instead, to subvert the off option to being the same as on, one could just copy the PostScript code (in `""`) that implements `On` to the `Off` part and keep both options:

```ppd
*TonerSaveMode Off/Not really off: "statusdict/tonersave known{statusdict begin true tonersave end}if"
```

For an option with no choices, it should be possible to remove the `OpenUI/CloseUI` part, so that it is not available to the user, but then I don't know if the `TonerSaveMode` code gets output at all. You'll need to try. (The `OrderDependency` helps put the code in the right order with all the other emitted code. There is a `NonUIOrderDependency` that might be needed instead).

In the header of the PPD you would probably need to change the `NickName` and `ModelName`.

Comment: Thanks, that should be a way to do it.

Another way seems to be to wrap the backend with a specific filter, Tea4CUPS (https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSTea4CUPS).

Quote : "A question which is sometimes seen concerns wanting to enforce default printer settings for applications and printing from the command line. It might be because some users on a network don't have the patience to check their printer settings or maybe it is seen as desirable to limit the alteration of some settings on an expensive-to-run colour printer. Within CUPS there is no surefire way of achieving this".

Comment: I didn't have a thorough look into it yet, but it seems to have a TEAOPTIONS feature to override the print job options. Seems to be the right tool for that (http://www.pykota.com/software/tea4cups).

Comment: Hi again, I just tried your idea. It works perfectly. All I had to do i modify /etc/cups/ppd/myDRAFTprinter.ppd and comment the "*OpenUI *ColorModel/Output Mode: PickOne" and "*OpenUI *OutputMode/Print Quality: PickOne " sections. It works perfectly. Only funny thing is, LibreOffice still shows the color and print mode options (but gray/draft is enforced, no matter what options the user chooses in LibreOffice). Other applications like Firefox don't show color and output mode dialogs anymore. It seems LibreOffice does its own thing to build its print dialogs. Anyway, it works

Comment: Beware that disabling the GUI is one aspect only; you may also need to emit some PostScript or other code to tell the printer what to do. Eg, a printer might keep a setting from a previous job for the next job without an explicit piece of change code. More probably each job implies some standard settings in the printer, but they might be the opposite of what you want. Also, the PostScript code could still be edited manually into the document before submitting it to CUPS!

Comment: " a printer might keep a setting from a previous job for the next job without an explicit piece of change code" : yes I just noticed that. The trick is to not disabling entirely the GUI, but just leaving 1 entry in each list (KGray for ColorModel, and FastDraft for the OutputMode), and specify DefaultColorModel (KGray) and DefaultOutputMode (FastDraft). This ways the print options are explicitly set.

Comment: "Also, the PostScript code could still be edited manually into the document before submitting it to CUPS!". As for that...I doubt my kids will be able to do that ;-)